# Element.insertAdjacentHTML() API throws error in chrome 55.0.2883.87

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I found the explaination about the API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), which tells me the second parameter is a string.

It's perform normal in firefox. However, in chrome, it shows the errors below:

[image: errors about <code>Element.insertAdjacentHTML() API</code> in chrome]

I just curious about what makes this? Is it because the api is still stay Working Draft status and different browsers do the different implementation?

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">
        <ul>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    //normal
    // var pTag=document.createElement("p");
    // div.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend",pTag);

    //throw error:
    // Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentElement' on 'Element': parameter 2 is not of type 'Element'.
    var txt = "<p>testtest</p>";
    div.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend",txt);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are reading the documentation of `insertAdjacentHTML` but you use `insertAdjacentElement`

Comment: @RolandStarke sorry it's my carelessness, thx~

Comment: Ugh... just did the same thing.  Reading the wrong documentation... years later another human doing the same exact thing... ok... correct documentation is insertAdjacentElement because that's the function I'm actually trying to use.

Comment: I can't believe, I also did the same mistake

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just Change `div.insertAdjacentElement` to `div.insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Coding revoltion</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="parent">
        <ul class="ul"></ul>
    </div>



    <script src="dom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">
        <ul>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>xxx</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    //normal
    // var pTag=document.createElement("p");
    // div.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend",pTag);

    //throw error:
    // Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentElement' on 'Element': parameter 2 is not of type 'Element'.
    var txt = "<p>testtest</p>";
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",txt);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The parameters are incorrect. The second parameter should be html element, in your case it's a string.

Answer (score 3):

Your `txt` variable must be an element. You can try this :

```
var txt = document.createElement("p")

txt.innerHTML = "testtest";
div.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend",txt);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have change **div.insertAdjacentElement** to **div.insertAdjacentHTML**:

and it will work for me

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to insert new block of elements :

1. insertAdjacentElement(position, element) 
    The second parameter should be an element and not html text.
   E.g.

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
parentElement.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',newDiv);
```

2. insertAdjacentHTML(position, text)
   *text* is valid html text or xml.
   e.g.

```js
var newDiv = `<div>This is a new div</div>
                <p> Hello !! </p>`;
parentDiv.addAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a new html element programatically **var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');** then assign your string to newly created object **htmlObject.innerHTML=htmlString**;.

```
 var htmlString = `<div class="item clearfix" id="income-${obj.id}">
            <div class="item__description">${obj.descripiton}</div>
            <div class="right clearfix">
                <div class="item__value">${obj.value}</div>
                <div class="item__delete">
                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
 var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
 htmlObject.innerHTML=htmlString;
 document.querySelector(".income__list").insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', htmlObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Obj.innerHTML or Obj.insertAdjacentHTML() if you want to continue with String HTML

```
const html = `
    <li>enter code here
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">${ title }</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white">${ content }</div>enter code here
    </li>
`;
PARENTELEMENT.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```